# AS400 subscription to SQL Server 2008 R2 Std

Tags: sql-server-2008, ibm-midrange, merge-replication, transactional-replication

I am aware that you can create a subscription on an AS400 box to a SQL Server box. My question is, can you have replication if you do not have active journals going on some of the AS400 tables?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do, and explain your reason(s) for wanting to do it.

Comment: i want to replicate data from AS400 to SQL.  I am only going to be replicating 5-8 tables.  The reason I want to replicate is to ensure I have the most recent data for cube processing and reporting.